# How to write some HTML from lambda

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to write in my view some HTML from lambda, I've tried

```
@Html.Raw(Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Note))
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Note)
MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Note).ToString())

@(new HtmlString(Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Note).ToString()))
```

But every time in my page I have `<p>Ciao Ciao</p>`

How can I write HTML tag from lambda?

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're expecting the output to be. You have some code and some output. What's the problem?

Comment: I have to write some tag from lamba but if i use @Html.Raw(Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Note))  in my html there isn't correct tag with < P > but it will be translated with &; and other char

Comment: why do you have to use lambda?

Comment: scaffolding write it for me....

Answer (score 0):

You can just append the HTML data into your `.cshtml` page as below.

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Note)
```

Comment: Error...model doesn't exists in this context, 'ive used raw as you see @Html.Raw(Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Note)) in my question but not work

Comment: @Topo capital `M` .. `Model`

Comment: @Topo glad to help, you can mark this as answer if it helped you resolve your issue